# Move string in specific cell to another cell in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Given the following df:

```
my_dict = {'Municipio': {0: '* Barranquitas', 1: '* Bayamón', 2: '* Cabo Rojo', 3: '* Caguas', 4: '* Camuy'}, 
           'Frecuencia %': {0: '656 0.8', 1: '6307 8.0', 2: '* Orocovis  397 0.5', 3: '0.2 3726 4.7', 4: '0.4 745 0.9'},
           'Municipio 2': {0: '* Naguabo', 1: '* Naranjito', 2: 'nan', 3: '* Patillas', 4: '* Peñuelas'}}
my_df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)
```

How could I use the value in the index `[2,1]` to place it in the index `[2,2]`? After using it I want to remove it from `[2,1]`.
[image]

Comment: Is the condition.... if nan, then move string portion to nan?

Comment: @JoeFerndz No, the condition doesn't work because there are other `nan` who don't need that change. It's just for that cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a brute force solution. You can use iloc and string position to do the assignment.

```
import pandas as pd
my_dict = {'Municipio': {0: '* Barranquitas', 1: '* Bayamón', 2: '* Cabo Rojo', 3: '* Caguas', 4: '* Camuy'}, 
           'Frecuencia %': {0: '656 0.8', 1: '6307 8.0', 2: '* Orocovis  397 0.5', 3: '0.2 3726 4.7', 4: '0.4 745 0.9'},
           'Municipio 2': {0: '* Naguabo', 1: '* Naranjito', 2: 'nan', 3: '* Patillas', 4: '* Peñuelas'}}
my_df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)


my_df.iloc[2,2] = my_df.iloc[2,1][:10]
my_df.iloc[2,1] = my_df.iloc[2,1][10:]

print (my_df)
```

Output:

```
        Municipio  Frecuencia %  Municipio 2
0  * Barranquitas       656 0.8    * Naguabo
1       * Bayamón      6307 8.0  * Naranjito
2     * Cabo Rojo       397 0.5   * Orocovis
3        * Caguas  0.2 3726 4.7   * Patillas
4         * Camuy   0.4 745 0.9   * Peñuelas
```

However, if you want to just swap the values of two cells, you can do this:

```
my_df.iloc[2,1], my_df.iloc[2,2]  = my_df.iloc[2,2], my_df.iloc[2,1]
```

The solution will be:

```
        Municipio  Frecuencia %          Municipio 2
0  * Barranquitas       656 0.8            * Naguabo
1       * Bayamón      6307 8.0          * Naranjito
2     * Cabo Rojo           nan  * Orocovis  397 0.5
3        * Caguas  0.2 3726 4.7           * Patillas
4         * Camuy   0.4 745 0.9           * Peñuelas
```

Since you want to extract a string with `'* letters'` from [2,1] into [2,2] and leave the remaining portion of the values in [2,1], you can use regEx to extract the value.

```
import pandas as pd
import re
my_dict = {'Municipio': {0: '* Barranquitas', 1: '* Bayamón', 2: '* Cabo Rojo', 3: '* Caguas', 4: '* Camuy'}, 
           'Frecuencia %': {0: '656 0.8', 1: '6307 8.0', 2: '* Orocovis  397 0.5', 3: '0.2 3726 4.7', 4: '0.4 745 0.9'},
           'Municipio 2': {0: '* Naguabo', 1: '* Naranjito', 2: 'nan', 3: '* Patillas', 4: '* Peñuelas'}}
my_df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)

print (my_df)

my_df.iloc[2,2] = re.search('\* \w+',my_df.iloc[2,1],0)[0] #first value will be the required text string
my_df.iloc[2,1] = re.split('\* \w+ ',my_df.iloc[2,1],1)[1] #the second part is the numbers
print (my_df)
```

The output will be as follows:

```
        Municipio         Frecuencia %  Municipio 2
0  * Barranquitas              656 0.8    * Naguabo
1       * Bayamón             6307 8.0  * Naranjito
2     * Cabo Rojo  * Orocovis  397 0.5          nan
3        * Caguas         0.2 3726 4.7   * Patillas
4         * Camuy          0.4 745 0.9   * Peñuelas

        Municipio  Frecuencia %  Municipio 2
0  * Barranquitas       656 0.8    * Naguabo
1       * Bayamón      6307 8.0  * Naranjito
2     * Cabo Rojo       397 0.5   * Orocovis
3        * Caguas  0.2 3726 4.7   * Patillas
4         * Camuy   0.4 745 0.9   * Peñuelas
```

Note, we cannot use iloc[].str as we are dealing with only one cell. If it was a set of rows, then we could have used iloc[].str.

By specifying the split to be n numbers, we are ensuring that all the values are stored into the columns.

```
my_df.iloc[2,2] = re.search('\* \w+',my_df.iloc[2,1],0)[0]
my_df.iloc[2,1] = re.split('\* \w+ ',my_df.iloc[2,1],1)[1]
```

The above conditions with .iloc[],0 we are ensuring it searches and gives us the first item only. Similarly with iloc[],1 we are splits into 2 parts and picking the 2nd item (index starts from 0 so 1 is 2nd element). Below, I have modified [2,1] to have multiple *+space+letter+space+number pattern. However, I am still getting the expected results of extracting only the first *+space+letter to column [2,2]

```
        Municipio               Frecuencia %  Municipio 2
0  * Barranquitas                    656 0.8    * Naguabo
1       * Bayamón                   6307 8.0  * Naranjito
2     * Cabo Rojo  * Orocovis  397 * and 0.5          nan
3        * Caguas               0.2 3726 4.7   * Patillas
4         * Camuy                0.4 745 0.9   * Peñuelas


        Municipio    Frecuencia %  Municipio 2
0  * Barranquitas         656 0.8    * Naguabo
1       * Bayamón        6307 8.0  * Naranjito
2     * Cabo Rojo   397 * and 0.5   * Orocovis
3        * Caguas    0.2 3726 4.7   * Patillas
4         * Camuy     0.4 745 0.9   * Peñuelas
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, it works well. But let's imagine the word that is written is a shorter or longer one. The solution would stop working because it depends on the count of each character. I was thinking that a better solution should be related to the number of elements separated by a space (`* Florida` would be equal to `* FL` because they both have an element, a space and another element). This way I could ask to separate the string by spaces and get the last two elements and it would not depend on the size of each word. But I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Will the pattern always be `* varying alphabets numbers`?  Starts with `*`, then space then alphabets then space then numbers space numbers ... etc? And we want to extract * space alphabets?

Comment: Yes. Asterisk+space+letters+space+number+space+number.

Comment: @StevenGonzález, see updated response. Let me know if this addresses your ask

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I had it marked as the accepted answer. However, I think a good idea would be to use: `my_df.iloc[2,1].split()[-2:]`. My only issue with this approach is that it results in a list and not a string.

Comment: `re.split('\* \w+',my_df.iloc[2,1],1)[-1]` resultss in `'  397 0.5'`. How do I get rid of the space in front of the first number `'  397 0.5'`?

Comment: re.split('\* \w+',my_df.iloc[2,1],1)[-1][1:] will remove the spaces. I am hesitant to use the extra space inside the regex. Have to test it. The [1:] will exclude the space. Let me see how I can improve the accuracy. Will work on it later this evening

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can move the cell by using the **iloc**. 
[image]

This is your current dataframe. We want to move [2,1] to place it in the index [2,2]. For that just assign [2,2] the value at [2,1] using iloc and then to remove it you can just replace the value at [2,1] with nan.

```
my_df.iloc[2,2] = my_df.iloc[2,1]
my_df.iloc[2,1] = np.nan
```

After running the above command you'll get the following dataframe:-
[image]